# Audio Broadcasting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, broadcasting

I want to do an i-phone application for broadcast audio LIVE over the internet..Anyone please guide me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Streaming Audio Clips from iPhone to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727205/streaming-audio-clips-from-iphone-to-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HI,
i created the broadcast audio LIVE over the internet use of AudioStream Files.
For the reference of Audiostreamer 
[AudioStreamer](http://code.google.com/p/audiostreamer-meta/source/browse/trunk/Classes/AudioStreamer.m?r=4).

For Download in github
[Github Download](https://github.com/waltertyree/AudioStreamer)

Answer (score 1):

try winamp server